# Multiply rate & Revenue based on currency

Tags: sql

There are two tables one with **Product-Name**, **revenue**, **Currency** AND other with **currency** & **rate**

I need to convert the Revenue based on the rate:

Like: **If** Table1.Currecy = Table2.Currecy_code **then** revenue * rate **else** 'NA'

it is a long list of currencies.

*could you please tell me which query will work to get this result.*

FYI: I am using Athena database-dbeaver, not sure which sql that is.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use left join with `case when` expression

```
select Product_name,currency,
(case when rate is null then 'NA' else cast(revenue* rate as varchar2) end) revenue
from table1 left join table2 on Table1.Currecy = Table2.Currecy_code
```

Comment: I am getting the error: "All Case results must be the same type: varchar(2)". The rate is double, revenue is also double data type.

Comment: Then you need  to cast revenue*rate to string. Need to know which dbms you are using. It can be cast(revenue*rate as varchar) or cast(revenue*rate as varchar2)